# Encouraging more berries

Tags: growth, blueberries

I have different types of blueberry bushes-from 1 year, to 10 years. I have done all the recommended things to have healthy plants. They all have lots of leaves and do make blueberries, but not so many.The bushes are healthy.I live in  zone 7.  I use peat moss and soil acidifyer(I live in clay country). I fertilize with holly-tone, I deep mulch with straw and rich compost, I prune in winter, I water in summer. What else can I do to encourage the plants to put on more blossoms and berries?